# Adding an answer to closed question, though question may be obsolete

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, unanswered-questions

I've nominated this question for reopening

[Cannot remove blue "nested" grid/rectangles in QGIS canvas?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/183352/cannot-remove-blue-nested-grid-rectangles-in-qgis-canvas)

I've found the cause, or at least what caused this blue quadtree, yet since then the QGIS version and the Plugin version have been upgraded and this bug is apparently fixed.

Is it still relevant? people may be using older versions, and a general restart of QGIS 'fixes' this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have re-opened that question.

I suspect that answering it is of limited value, as you imply, but when users wish to answer closed questions, they can usually be re-opened with a simple flag of type `Other` to get a moderator's attention to do so.

When answering perhaps you can make sure to specify the version limits of the issue as you know it.